# How to use one port for two applications?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, nginx, openconnect

I had https on my website very well until recently that my government decided to block almost every VPN protocols and right now only `openconnect` works correctly.

Therefore I installed and configured `openconnect` on my server, unfortunately it doesn't let me start the service as my `nginx` was using 443 port (`openconnect` uses port 443), so I removed the https configuration from my `nginx` and run `openconnect` service.

Now I want to configure https on my `nginx` as well.

I know that one port cannot be used by two applications/services normally. But is there a way I can use port 443 on `nginx` and `openconnect` both and have something like `haproxy` or `traefik` or `nginx` itself to supervise them and 
make them both understand if a VPN Client or Browser wants to connect?

Edit:
I found this url but I wonder if it's my problem.

https://ocserv.gitlab.io/www/recipes-ocserv-multihost.html

Comment: A second IP address would make things easier. Would that be an option?

Comment: Also you could configure ocserv to use another port

Comment: @SebastianStark Both is not possible.
Second IP address doesn't worth it due to prices and I don't use very much of that server to purchase more.
Actually I gave openconnect user to some of my friends who are not into computer at all and I don't want them to get confused with another port, besides I don't know if every openconnect client supports using another port.

Comment: The link you found will probably solve the issue.  But, you'd need `haproxy` or `sniproxy`, not nginx, to manage that type of setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ocserv.gitlab.io/www/recipes-ocserv-multihost.html

This link solved my problem but it needed some changes.

In /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg you should change two lines of `default` section from

```
mode http
option httplog
```

to

```
mode tcp
option tcplog
```

Also there is a line in this site's code which goes:

```
use-server server-vpn if vpn-app
use-server server-web if web-app
use-server server-vpn if !vpn-app !web-app
```

That didn't work for me and this way it routes all the traffic to server-vpn but after I commented the third line out I could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, as @amin-vakil pointed out, I found that using a reverse proxy (like haproxy or nginx) in front of ocserv works well, EXCEPT, there is one catch. If you want to be able to use DTLS, and you're using haproxy, haproxy doesn't by default proxy out UDP (which is used by DTLS), thus I ended up using haproxy to ONLY route TCP connections, and have ocserv listen on the main interface for UDP, just on a different port. Since DTLS is negotiated after an initial connection is made, by ocserv DECLARING the port to be used for negotiation, this doesnt seem tobe an issue.

My network setup looks something like this:

```
                   VPS BOX                                                                 
                |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|  
                |              others *< ----+                                              |  
                |                            |      vpn.<domain>.com rev proxy pass-thru to |  
                |                |------@HA Proxy -----------|  127.0.1.1:443               |  
                |                |                           | (SSL handled by ocserv)      |  
                |               [TCP 80 & TCP 443]           |                              |  
inet --> public IP - > 10.10.0.5                             |---> 127.0.1.1                |  
                |         [udp 44443]                               [tcp 443]               |  
                |          \                                         |                      |  
                |           \                                        @                      |  
                |            \-------------------------------------=@ocserv listening on    |  
                |                                 tcp 127.0.1.1:443 & udp 10.10.0.5:44443   |  
                |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```